# Dynamically allocate and add a structure inside a linked chain

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, struct, allocation

I am facing a problem concerning the dynamic allocation of structure, a linked chain containing a pointer to a structure to be more specific.

Code of the linked chain:

```
typedef struct Queue Queue;
struct Queue{
    Real* elmt;
    Queue* next;
    Queue* prev;
};
```

So, this struct is circular, with next pointing to the next

Code of struct Real(which represents):

```
typedef struct Real Real;
struct Real{
    int* nb; //int array containing the number
    size_t size;
    int neg; /*0=positive 1=negative*/
    int com; /*-1 = no comma, otherwise integer indicating the position*/
};
```

So, as explained, I wish to dynamically allocate a queue containing several elements, so I created this function:

```
Queue* mallocQueueElmt(const Real* arg){
    Queue* res=NULL;

    res=mallocQueue();

    res->elmt=NULL;
    res->elmt=mallocReal(arg->size);

    memmove(res->elmt->nb, arg->nb, sizeof(int)*arg->size);

    res->elmt->com=arg->com;
    res->elmt->neg=arg->neg;

    res->next=res;
    res->prev=res;

    return res;
}
```

`mallocReal()` just returns a pointer pointing at a Real structure containing a pointer(meaning the member `nb` of the structure `Real`) pointing at an array(dynamically allocated) of int with a size equal to `arg->size`

This works, I tested it with a function :

```
void printQueue(Queue* arg){
    Queue* cur=NULL;
    cur=arg->prev;

    if(cur == arg->prev){;
        printReal(cur->elmt);
        printf(" ");
    }
    else    
        while(cur != arg){
            cur=cur->next;
            if(cur->elmt){
                printReal(cur->elmt);
                printf(" ");
            }else{
                printf("no element ");
            }
        }


}
```

But when I try to add an element, thanks to this function:

```
Queue* addElement(Queue* arg, const Real* arg1){
    Queue* res=NULL;

    res=mallocQueue();

    res->elmt=NULL;
    res->elmt=mallocReal(arg1->size);

    memmove(res->elmt->nb, arg1->nb, sizeof(int)*arg1->size);

    res->elmt->neg=arg1->neg;
    res->elmt->com=arg1->com;

    res->prev=arg->prev;
    res->next=arg;
    res->prev->next=res;
    arg->prev=res;

    res=arg;

    return res; 
}
```

and recall `printQueue()`, then only the second element(so added with `addElement()`) is
displayed, and nothing anormal happened, everything seemed to be running fine.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement in printQueue will always only print the lastly added item in the queue.

Try something like this instead:

```
void printQueue(Queue* arg){
    Queue* cur=arg;

    do {
        printReal(cur->elmt);
        printf(" ");

        cur=cur->next;
    } while (cur != arg);
}
```